# iText DSS without timestamp

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

After several days of work, i got my PDFs LTV enabled (yay!).

With the adobe pdf reader i can see a second revision/signature now. As i understand, that's because of the signed timestamp in the DSS.

As i have read on several sites, to enable LTV using DSS, a second timestamp isn't needed.

I'm using the addLtv method described in the [iText whitepaper](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fitextpdf.com%2Fbook%2Fdigitalsignatures%2F&ei=J0m1VI3XL9L3ao_pgMgL&usg=AFQjCNFfBcfficf4L-uNM0u3OZ9rlw00_w&bvm=bv.83339334,d.d2s)

The timestamp is added by this line of code:

```
LtvTimestamp.timestamp(appearance, tsa, null);
```

But if i remove this line, my output PDF is empty.

How can i create a LTV enabled PDF without a timestamped DSS?

-e-

if i just do

```
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

i get this error:

```
com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: Signature defined. Must be closed in PdfSignatureAppearance.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling LTV for timestamp signature in PDF document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892960/enabling-ltv-for-timestamp-signature-in-pdf-document)

Answer (score 2):

LTV always require a timestamp. If you look at [PAdES part 4](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts%5C102700_102799%5C10277804%5C01.01.02_60%5Cts_10277804v010102p.pdf) in section 4.3:

"Validation of documents without document Time-stamps is outside the scope of this profile."

In other words you can create a document without timestamp but you can't validate it, which kind of defeats the purpose of signing in the first place.

Comment: Ok, so there is no possibility to have a LTV enabled PDF witouth a second signature?

Comment: As written in my question, i already tried to add no timestamp and call stamper.close() instead (as supposed by the answer in your link). But then i get the error mentioned in my question. -e- my bad, should have read all the answers. I constructed the stamper the wrong way.