# iText7 LtvVerification.addVerification not enabling LTV

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, itext7

We are trying to make the signed signature LTV enabled. I am using the below code to add verification. When signature.isTsp() is false, the PDF says `Signature is not LTV enabled`, though in the other case (signature.isTsp() is true) it shows as valid. 
When we open the PDF and try to manually add verification info by right clicking on the signature it enables LTV without any issue. Not sure what we are missing here. 
Any input will be highly helpful.

```
// Adds LTV-enabled information to the PDF document.
private ByteArrayOutputStream addLtv(final IOcspClient ocspClient,
                                     final ByteArrayOutputStream docStream)
        throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final InputStream signedStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(docStream.toByteArray());
    final PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(signedStream);
    final PdfDocument document =
            new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(outputStream), new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
    final LtvVerification verification = new LtvVerification(document);
    final SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(document);

    final List<String> signatureNames = signatureUtil.getSignatureNames();
    final String sigName = signatureNames.get(signatureNames.size() - 1);
    final PdfPKCS7 signature = signatureUtil.verifySignature(sigName);

    final CrlClientOnline crl = new CrlClientOnline();
    if (!signature.isTsp()) {
        for (final String name: signatureNames) {
            addVerificationInfo(ocspClient, verification, crl, name);
        }
    } else {
        addVerificationInfo(ocspClient, verification, crl, sigName);
    }

    document.close();

    return outputStream;
}

private void addVerificationInfo(final IOcspClient ocspClient, final LtvVerification verification,
                                 final CrlClientOnline crl,
                                 final String name) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    verification.addVerification(
            name, ocspClient, crl,
            LtvVerification.CertificateOption.WHOLE_CHAIN,
            LtvVerification.Level.OCSP_CRL,
            LtvVerification.CertificateInclusion.NO);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason why your code does not always LTV-enable PDFs is that it does not add validation information related to OCSP response signatures.

*It doesn't add validation information for CRL signatures, either. As CRLs usually are signed by the issuer certificate of the signer certificate, though, and as validation information for that issuer certificate have already been added in the context of the main signature, LTV-enabling usually does not fail because of missing CRL signature validation information. So if you can use CRLs only, chances are that your code indeed already does LTV-enable PDFs.*

In the context of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51481392/1729265) (in particular its section "An approach using an own utility class") I created an utility class `AdobeLtvEnabling` for iText 5 allowing to LTV-enable PDFs, mostly using bits and pieces found in iText 5 itself. In contrast to your code it does add validation information for OCSP response signatures (and also for CRL signatures).

Here you can find the port of that class to iText 7.

#### The utility class `AdobeLtvEnabling`

This utility class bundles the code required for LTV enabling the signatures in a signed PDF document. The code pieces mostly have been taken from existing iText code. The main reason why this class has not been designed to derive from `LtvVerification` is that required variables and methods from that class are `private`. As the class originally has been written for iText 5, some iText-5-isms probably can be found in it...

```java
public class AdobeLtvEnabling {
    /**
     * Use this constructor with a {@link PdfDocument} in append mode. Otherwise
     * the existing signatures will be damaged.
     */
    public AdobeLtvEnabling(PdfDocument pdfDocument) {
        this.pdfDocument = pdfDocument;
    }

    /**
     * Call this method to have LTV information added to the {@link PdfDocument}
     * given in the constructor.
     */
    public void enable(IOcspClient ocspClient, ICrlClient crlClient) throws OperatorException, GeneralSecurityException, IOException, StreamParsingException, OCSPException {
        SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument);

        List<String> names = signatureUtil.getSignatureNames();
        for (String name : names) {
            PdfPKCS7 pdfPKCS7 = signatureUtil.verifySignature(name, BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
            PdfSignature sig = signatureUtil.getSignature(name);
            List<X509Certificate> certificatesToCheck = new ArrayList<>();
            certificatesToCheck.add(pdfPKCS7.getSigningCertificate());
            while (!certificatesToCheck.isEmpty()) {
                X509Certificate certificate = certificatesToCheck.remove(0);
                addLtvForChain(certificate, ocspClient, crlClient, getSignatureHashKey(sig));
            }
        }

        outputDss();
    }

    //
    // the actual LTV enabling methods
    //
    void addLtvForChain(X509Certificate certificate, IOcspClient ocspClient, ICrlClient crlClient, PdfName key) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, StreamParsingException, OperatorCreationException, OCSPException {
        ValidationData validationData = new ValidationData();

        while (certificate != null) {
            System.out.println(certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
            X509Certificate issuer = getIssuerCertificate(certificate);
            validationData.certs.add(certificate.getEncoded());
            byte[] ocspResponse = ocspClient.getEncoded(certificate, issuer, null);
            if (ocspResponse != null) {
                System.out.println("  with OCSP response");
                validationData.ocsps.add(ocspResponse);
                X509Certificate ocspSigner = getOcspSignerCertificate(ocspResponse);
                if (ocspSigner != null) {
                    System.out.printf("  signed by %s\n", ocspSigner.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
                }
                addLtvForChain(ocspSigner, ocspClient, crlClient, getOcspHashKey(ocspResponse));
            } else {
               Collection<byte[]> crl = crlClient.getEncoded(certificate, null);
               if (crl != null && !crl.isEmpty()) {
                   System.out.printf("  with %s CRLs\n", crl.size());
                   validationData.crls.addAll(crl);
                   for (byte[] crlBytes : crl) {
                       addLtvForChain(null, ocspClient, crlClient, getCrlHashKey(crlBytes));
                   }
               }
            }
            certificate = issuer;
        }

        validated.put(key, validationData);
    }

    void outputDss() throws IOException {
        PdfDictionary dss = new PdfDictionary();
        PdfDictionary vrim = new PdfDictionary();
        PdfArray ocsps = new PdfArray();
        PdfArray crls = new PdfArray();
        PdfArray certs = new PdfArray();

        PdfCatalog catalog = pdfDocument.getCatalog();
        if (pdfDocument.getPdfVersion().compareTo(PdfVersion.PDF_2_0) < 0) {
            catalog.addDeveloperExtension(PdfDeveloperExtension.ESIC_1_7_EXTENSIONLEVEL5);
            catalog.addDeveloperExtension(new PdfDeveloperExtension(PdfName.ADBE, new PdfName("1.7"), 8));
        }

        for (PdfName vkey : validated.keySet()) {
            PdfArray ocsp = new PdfArray();
            PdfArray crl = new PdfArray();
            PdfArray cert = new PdfArray();
            PdfDictionary vri = new PdfDictionary();
            for (byte[] b : validated.get(vkey).crls) {
                PdfStream ps = new PdfStream(b);
                ps.setCompressionLevel(CompressionConstants.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
                ps.makeIndirect(pdfDocument);
                crl.add(ps);
                crls.add(ps);
                crls.setModified();
            }
            for (byte[] b : validated.get(vkey).ocsps) {
                b = buildOCSPResponse(b);
                PdfStream ps = new PdfStream(b);
                ps.setCompressionLevel(CompressionConstants.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
                ps.makeIndirect(pdfDocument);
                ocsp.add(ps);
                ocsps.add(ps);
                ocsps.setModified();
            }
            for (byte[] b : validated.get(vkey).certs) {
                PdfStream ps = new PdfStream(b);
                ps.setCompressionLevel(CompressionConstants.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
                ps.makeIndirect(pdfDocument);
                cert.add(ps);
                certs.add(ps);
                certs.setModified();
            }
            if (ocsp.size() > 0) {
                ocsp.makeIndirect(pdfDocument);
                vri.put(PdfName.OCSP, ocsp);
            }
            if (crl.size() > 0) {
                crl.makeIndirect(pdfDocument);
                vri.put(PdfName.CRL, crl);
            }
            if (cert.size() > 0) {
                cert.makeIndirect(pdfDocument);
                vri.put(PdfName.Cert, cert);
            }
            vri.put(PdfName.TU, new PdfDate().getPdfObject());
            vri.makeIndirect(pdfDocument);
            vrim.put(vkey, vri);
        }
        vrim.makeIndirect(pdfDocument);
        vrim.setModified();
        dss.put(PdfName.VRI, vrim);
        if (ocsps.size() > 0) {
            ocsps.makeIndirect(pdfDocument);
            dss.put(PdfName.OCSPs, ocsps);
        }
        if (crls.size() > 0) {
            crls.makeIndirect(pdfDocument);
            dss.put(PdfName.CRLs, crls);
        }
        if (certs.size() > 0) {
            certs.makeIndirect(pdfDocument);
            dss.put(PdfName.Certs, certs);
        }

        dss.makeIndirect(pdfDocument);
        dss.setModified();
        catalog.put(PdfName.DSS, dss);
    }

    //
    // VRI signature hash key calculation
    //
    static PdfName getCrlHashKey(byte[] crlBytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, CRLException, CertificateException {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509CRL crl = (X509CRL)cf.generateCRL(new ByteArrayInputStream(crlBytes));
        byte[] signatureBytes = crl.getSignature();
        DEROctetString octetString = new DEROctetString(signatureBytes);
        byte[] octetBytes = octetString.getEncoded();
        byte[] octetHash = hashBytesSha1(octetBytes);
        PdfName octetName = new PdfName(convertToHex(octetHash));
        return octetName;
    }

    static PdfName getOcspHashKey(byte[] basicResponseBytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        BasicOCSPResponse basicResponse = BasicOCSPResponse.getInstance(basicResponseBytes);
        byte[] signatureBytes = basicResponse.getSignature().getBytes();
        DEROctetString octetString = new DEROctetString(signatureBytes);
        byte[] octetBytes = octetString.getEncoded();
        byte[] octetHash = hashBytesSha1(octetBytes);
        PdfName octetName = new PdfName(convertToHex(octetHash));
        return octetName;
    }

    static PdfName getSignatureHashKey(PdfSignature sig) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        PdfString contents = sig.getContents();
        byte[] bc = PdfEncodings.convertToBytes(contents.getValue(), null);
        if (PdfName.ETSI_RFC3161.equals(sig.getSubFilter())) {
            try (   ASN1InputStream din = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bc)) ) {
                ASN1Primitive pkcs = din.readObject();
                bc = pkcs.getEncoded();
            }
        }
        byte[] bt = hashBytesSha1(bc);
        return new PdfName(convertToHex(bt));
    }

    static byte[] hashBytesSha1(byte[] b) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest sh = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        return sh.digest(b);
    }

    static String convertToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        ByteBuffer buf = new ByteBuffer();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            buf.appendHex(b);
        }
        return PdfEncodings.convertToString(buf.toByteArray(), null).toUpperCase();
    }

    //
    // OCSP response helpers
    //
    static X509Certificate getOcspSignerCertificate(byte[] basicResponseBytes) throws CertificateException, OCSPException, OperatorCreationException {
        JcaX509CertificateConverter converter = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
        BasicOCSPResponse borRaw = BasicOCSPResponse.getInstance(basicResponseBytes);
        BasicOCSPResp bor = new BasicOCSPResp(borRaw);

        for (final X509CertificateHolder x509CertificateHolder : bor.getCerts()) {
            X509Certificate x509Certificate = converter.getCertificate(x509CertificateHolder);

            JcaContentVerifierProviderBuilder jcaContentVerifierProviderBuilder = new JcaContentVerifierProviderBuilder();
            jcaContentVerifierProviderBuilder.setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
            final PublicKey publicKey = x509Certificate.getPublicKey();
            ContentVerifierProvider contentVerifierProvider = jcaContentVerifierProviderBuilder.build(publicKey);

            if (bor.isSignatureValid(contentVerifierProvider))
                return x509Certificate;
        }
        
        return null;
    }

    static byte[] buildOCSPResponse(byte[] BasicOCSPResponse) throws IOException {
        DEROctetString doctet = new DEROctetString(BasicOCSPResponse);
        ASN1EncodableVector v2 = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        v2.add(OCSPObjectIdentifiers.id_pkix_ocsp_basic);
        v2.add(doctet);
        ASN1Enumerated den = new ASN1Enumerated(0);
        ASN1EncodableVector v3 = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        v3.add(den);
        v3.add(new DERTaggedObject(true, 0, new DERSequence(v2)));            
        DERSequence seq = new DERSequence(v3);
        return seq.getEncoded();
    }

    //
    // X509 certificate related helpers
    //
    static X509Certificate getIssuerCertificate(X509Certificate certificate) throws IOException, StreamParsingException {
        String url = getCACURL(certificate);
        if (url != null && url.length() > 0) {
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
            if (con.getResponseCode() / 100 != 2) {
                throw new PdfException(PdfException.InvalidHttpResponse1).setMessageParams(con.getResponseCode());
            }
            InputStream inp = (InputStream) con.getContent();
            X509CertParser parser = new X509CertParser();
            parser.engineInit(new ByteArrayInputStream(StreamUtil.inputStreamToArray(inp)));
            return (X509Certificate) parser.engineRead();
        }
        return null;
    }

    static String getCACURL(X509Certificate certificate) {
        ASN1Primitive obj;
        try {
            obj = getExtensionValue(certificate, Extension.authorityInfoAccess.getId());
            if (obj == null) {
                return null;
            }
            ASN1Sequence AccessDescriptions = (ASN1Sequence) obj;
            for (int i = 0; i < AccessDescriptions.size(); i++) {
                ASN1Sequence AccessDescription = (ASN1Sequence) AccessDescriptions.getObjectAt(i);
                if ( AccessDescription.size() != 2 ) {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (AccessDescription.getObjectAt(0) instanceof ASN1ObjectIdentifier) {
                    ASN1ObjectIdentifier id = (ASN1ObjectIdentifier)AccessDescription.getObjectAt(0);
                    if ("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2".equals(id.getId())) {
                        ASN1Primitive description = (ASN1Primitive)AccessDescription.getObjectAt(1);
                        String AccessLocation =  getStringFromGeneralName(description);
                        if (AccessLocation == null) {
                            return "" ;
                        }
                        else {
                            return AccessLocation ;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    static ASN1Primitive getExtensionValue(X509Certificate certificate, String oid) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = certificate.getExtensionValue(oid);
        if (bytes == null) {
            return null;
        }
        ASN1InputStream aIn = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        ASN1OctetString octs = (ASN1OctetString) aIn.readObject();
        aIn = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(octs.getOctets()));
        return aIn.readObject();
    }

    static String getStringFromGeneralName(ASN1Primitive names) throws IOException {
        ASN1TaggedObject taggedObject = (ASN1TaggedObject) names ;
        return new String(ASN1OctetString.getInstance(taggedObject, false).getOctets(), "ISO-8859-1");
    }

    //
    // inner class
    //
    static class ValidationData {
        final List<byte[]> crls = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        final List<byte[]> ocsps = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        final List<byte[]> certs = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    }

    //
    // member variables
    //
    final PdfDocument pdfDocument;

    final Map<PdfName,ValidationData> validated = new HashMap<PdfName,ValidationData>();
}
```

*([AdobeLtvEnabling.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/AdobeLtvEnabling.java#L90))*

#### Example use

You can use the `AdobeLtvEnabling` class like this:

```java
try (   PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(TARGET);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter,
                new StampingProperties().preserveEncryption().useAppendMode())) {
    AdobeLtvEnabling adobeLtvEnabling = new AdobeLtvEnabling(pdfDocument);
    IOcspClient ocsp = new OcspClientBouncyCastle(null);
    ICrlClient crl = new CrlClientOnline();
    adobeLtvEnabling.enable(ocsp, crl);
}
```

*([MakeLtvEnabled](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/MakeLtvEnabled.java#L57) test `testLtvEnableSignWithoutLtv`)*

#### Limitations

As this code essentially is ported from the iText 5 code from the referenced answer, it also inherits the limitations listed in that answer:

The code works under some simplifying restrictions, in particular:

- signature time stamps are ignored,
- retrieved CRLs are assumed to be direct and complete,
- the complete certificate chains are assumed to be buildable using AIA entries.

You can improve the code accordingly if these restrictions are not acceptable for you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, the code worked like charm.