# I want to sign a pdf document with ITextSharp and return ltv pdf enabled file

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

The method receives pdf document as byte array that should be signed, certificate to sign with and TSA client and it returns signed document as byte array or null if there was error. Now it returns signed pdf document but it isnt LTV enabled.
Signed document must be LTV enabled. How do I make the document being returned LTV enabled? I'll be very grateful for any suggestions.

```
public byte[] Sign(byte[] document, X509Certificate2 certificate, ITSAClient tsaClient)
    {
    byte[] signedDocument = null;

    IExternalSignature signature = new X509Certificate2Signature(certificate, "SHA-1");
    Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser cp = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
    Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { cp.ReadCertificate(certificate.RawData) };

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(document);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, ms, '\0');

    PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance;
    sap.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED;
    sap.SignatureCreator = "NAME";
    sap.Reason = "REASON";
    sap.Contact = "CONTACT";
    sap.Location = "LOCATION";
    sap.SignDate = DateTime.Now;

    RectangleF rectangle = new RectangleF(400.98139f, 54.88828f, 530, 84.88828f);
    sap.Layer2Font = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1257, 7f);
    sap.Layer2Font.Color = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.RED;
    sap.Layer2Text = string.Format("Signed for testing: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy."));
    sap.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
    sap.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height), 1, null);

    MakeSignature.SignDetached(sap, signature, chain, null, null, tsaClient, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);

    st.Close();

    ms.Flush();
    signedDocument = ms.ToArray();
    ms.Close();

    reader.Close();

    return signedDocument;
}
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51481392/1729265) focuses on LTV enabling using iText 5 for Java and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51675015/1729265) on LTV enabling using iText 7 for Java. You merely have to port the variant applicable to your use case.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I'm using the itextShap library instead. Not itext. And i have very little understanding of java.

Comment: Plz can anyone direct me on how to covert [This java code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51481392/1729265) to C# and use itextSharp to enable ltv on pdf?

Comment: *"I'm using the itextShap library instead. Not itext."* - iTextSharp is the name of the port of iText from Java to C# up to the 5.5.x versions. Thus, you're nearly there. *"Plz can anyone direct me on how to covert This java code to C#"* - probably I'll have some spare time next week for that.

Comment: ok @mkl thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you cannot expect the signature creation step to return a LTV-enabled signature.

*Leonard Rosenthol (Adobe's prime PDF Guru) remarked [on the iText mailing list in early 2013](http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/LTV-tp4657297p4657327.html) that while it is possible to have the signature container itself already contain all the information required for a LTV enabled signature, this is very uncommon and not always possible.*

(There are exceptions, e.g. there was a Swisscom signing service generating signature containers with all the extra information required for a LTV enabled integrated PDF signature.)

Thus, in general you'll have to add all the missing information in a second step.

Such a second step, on the other hand, means that such a second pass may interfere with signing with `CertificationLevel = CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED` - the current PDF specification requires that even for such a certification level incremental updates are allowed if they contain only signature validation information but I have not yet seen Adobe Reader not complain about in such a case. So you might have to loosen your certification level for LTV enabling.

For iText 5 / Java and iText 7 / Java helper classes that execute this second step can be found in [this answer (iText 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51481392/1729265) and [this answer (iText 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51675015/1729265).

I have ported the Java helper class for iText 5 to C#:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.error_messages;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Ocsp;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Ocsp;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

[...]

class AdobeLtvEnabling
{
    /**
     * Use this constructor with a {@link PdfStamper} in append mode. Otherwise
     * the existing signatures will be damaged.
     */
    public AdobeLtvEnabling(PdfStamper pdfStamper)
    {
        this.pdfStamper = pdfStamper;
    }

    /**
     * Call this method to have LTV information added to the {@link PdfStamper}
     * given in the constructor.
     */
    public void enable(IOcspClient ocspClient, ICrlClient crlClient)
    {
        AcroFields fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
        bool encrypted = pdfStamper.Reader.IsEncrypted();

        List<String> names = fields.GetSignatureNames();
        foreach (String name in names)
        {
            PdfPKCS7 pdfPKCS7 = fields.VerifySignature(name);
            PdfDictionary signatureDictionary = fields.GetSignatureDictionary(name);
            X509Certificate certificate = pdfPKCS7.SigningCertificate;
            addLtvForChain(certificate, ocspClient, crlClient, getSignatureHashKey(signatureDictionary, encrypted));
        }

        outputDss();
    }

    //
    // the actual LTV enabling methods
    //
    void addLtvForChain(X509Certificate certificate, IOcspClient ocspClient, ICrlClient crlClient, PdfName key)
    {
        if (seenCertificates.Contains(certificate))
            return;
        seenCertificates.Add(certificate);
        ValidationData validationData = new ValidationData();

        while (certificate != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(certificate.SubjectDN);
            X509Certificate issuer = getIssuerCertificate(certificate);
            validationData.certs.Add(certificate.GetEncoded());
            byte[] ocspResponse = ocspClient.GetEncoded(certificate, issuer, null);
            if (ocspResponse != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  with OCSP response");
                validationData.ocsps.Add(ocspResponse);
                X509Certificate ocspSigner = getOcspSignerCertificate(ocspResponse);
                if (ocspSigner != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  signed by {0}\n", ocspSigner.SubjectDN);
                }
                addLtvForChain(ocspSigner, ocspClient, crlClient, getOcspHashKey(ocspResponse));
            }
            else
            {
                ICollection<byte[]> crl = crlClient.GetEncoded(certificate, null);
                if (crl != null && crl.Count > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  with {0} CRLs\n", crl.Count);
                    foreach (byte[] crlBytes in crl)
                    {
                        validationData.crls.Add(crlBytes);
                        addLtvForChain(null, ocspClient, crlClient, getCrlHashKey(crlBytes));
                    }
                }
            }
            certificate = issuer;
        }

        validated[key] = validationData;
    }

    void outputDss()
    {
        PdfWriter writer = pdfStamper.Writer;
        PdfReader reader = pdfStamper.Reader;

        PdfDictionary dss = new PdfDictionary();
        PdfDictionary vrim = new PdfDictionary();
        PdfArray ocsps = new PdfArray();
        PdfArray crls = new PdfArray();
        PdfArray certs = new PdfArray();

        writer.AddDeveloperExtension(PdfDeveloperExtension.ESIC_1_7_EXTENSIONLEVEL5);
        writer.AddDeveloperExtension(new PdfDeveloperExtension(PdfName.ADBE, new PdfName("1.7"), 8));

        PdfDictionary catalog = reader.Catalog;
        pdfStamper.MarkUsed(catalog);
        foreach (PdfName vkey in validated.Keys)
        {
            PdfArray ocsp = new PdfArray();
            PdfArray crl = new PdfArray();
            PdfArray cert = new PdfArray();
            PdfDictionary vri = new PdfDictionary();
            foreach (byte[] b in validated[vkey].crls)
            {
                PdfStream ps = new PdfStream(b);
                ps.FlateCompress();
                PdfIndirectReference iref = writer.AddToBody(ps, false).IndirectReference;
                crl.Add(iref);
                crls.Add(iref);
            }
            foreach (byte[] b in validated[vkey].ocsps)
            {
                PdfStream ps = new PdfStream(buildOCSPResponse(b));
                ps.FlateCompress();
                PdfIndirectReference iref = writer.AddToBody(ps, false).IndirectReference;
                ocsp.Add(iref);
                ocsps.Add(iref);
            }
            foreach (byte[] b in validated[vkey].certs)
            {
                PdfStream ps = new PdfStream(b);
                ps.FlateCompress();
                PdfIndirectReference iref = writer.AddToBody(ps, false).IndirectReference;
                cert.Add(iref);
                certs.Add(iref);
            }
            if (ocsp.Length > 0)
                vri.Put(PdfName.OCSP, writer.AddToBody(ocsp, false).IndirectReference);
            if (crl.Length > 0)
                vri.Put(PdfName.CRL, writer.AddToBody(crl, false).IndirectReference);
            if (cert.Length > 0)
                vri.Put(PdfName.CERT, writer.AddToBody(cert, false).IndirectReference);
            vri.Put(PdfName.TU, new PdfDate());
            vrim.Put(vkey, writer.AddToBody(vri, false).IndirectReference);
        }
        dss.Put(PdfName.VRI, writer.AddToBody(vrim, false).IndirectReference);
        if (ocsps.Length > 0)
            dss.Put(PdfName.OCSPS, writer.AddToBody(ocsps, false).IndirectReference);
        if (crls.Length > 0)
            dss.Put(PdfName.CRLS, writer.AddToBody(crls, false).IndirectReference);
        if (certs.Length > 0)
            dss.Put(PdfName.CERTS, writer.AddToBody(certs, false).IndirectReference);
        catalog.Put(PdfName.DSS, writer.AddToBody(dss, false).IndirectReference);
    }

    //
    // VRI signature hash key calculation
    //
    static PdfName getCrlHashKey(byte[] crlBytes)
    {
        X509Crl crl = new X509Crl(CertificateList.GetInstance(crlBytes)); 
        byte[] signatureBytes = crl.GetSignature();
        DerOctetString octetString = new DerOctetString(signatureBytes);
        byte[] octetBytes = octetString.GetEncoded();
        byte[] octetHash = hashBytesSha1(octetBytes);
        PdfName octetName = new PdfName(Utilities.ConvertToHex(octetHash));
        return octetName;
    }

    static PdfName getOcspHashKey(byte[] basicResponseBytes)
    {
        BasicOcspResponse basicResponse = BasicOcspResponse.GetInstance(Asn1Sequence.GetInstance(basicResponseBytes));
        byte[] signatureBytes = basicResponse.Signature.GetBytes();
        DerOctetString octetString = new DerOctetString(signatureBytes);
        byte[] octetBytes = octetString.GetEncoded();
        byte[] octetHash = hashBytesSha1(octetBytes);
        PdfName octetName = new PdfName(Utilities.ConvertToHex(octetHash));
        return octetName;
    }

    static PdfName getSignatureHashKey(PdfDictionary dic, bool encrypted)
    {
        PdfString contents = dic.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS);
        byte[] bc = contents.GetOriginalBytes();
        if (PdfName.ETSI_RFC3161.Equals(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(dic.Get(PdfName.SUBFILTER))))
        {
            using (Asn1InputStream din = new Asn1InputStream(bc))
            {
                Asn1Object pkcs = din.ReadObject();
                bc = pkcs.GetEncoded();
            }
        }
        byte[] bt = hashBytesSha1(bc);
        return new PdfName(Utilities.ConvertToHex(bt));
    }

    static byte[] hashBytesSha1(byte[] b)
    {
        SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        return sha.ComputeHash(b);
    }

    //
    // OCSP response helpers
    //
    static X509Certificate getOcspSignerCertificate(byte[] basicResponseBytes)
    {
        BasicOcspResponse borRaw = BasicOcspResponse.GetInstance(Asn1Sequence.GetInstance(basicResponseBytes));
        BasicOcspResp bor = new BasicOcspResp(borRaw);

        foreach (X509Certificate x509Certificate in bor.GetCerts())
        {
            if (bor.Verify(x509Certificate.GetPublicKey()))
                return x509Certificate;
        }

        return null;
    }

    static byte[] buildOCSPResponse(byte[] BasicOCSPResponse)
    {
        DerOctetString doctet = new DerOctetString(BasicOCSPResponse);
        Asn1EncodableVector v2 = new Asn1EncodableVector();
        v2.Add(OcspObjectIdentifiers.PkixOcspBasic);
        v2.Add(doctet);
        DerEnumerated den = new DerEnumerated(0);
        Asn1EncodableVector v3 = new Asn1EncodableVector();
        v3.Add(den);
        v3.Add(new DerTaggedObject(true, 0, new DerSequence(v2)));            
        DerSequence seq = new DerSequence(v3);
        return seq.GetEncoded();
    }

    //
    // X509 certificate related helpers
    //
    static X509Certificate getIssuerCertificate(X509Certificate certificate)
    {
        String url = getCACURL(certificate);
        if (url != null && url.Length > 0)
        {
            HttpWebRequest con = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)con.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                throw new IOException(MessageLocalization.GetComposedMessage("invalid.http.response.1", (int)response.StatusCode));
            //Get Response
            Stream inp = response.GetResponseStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            MemoryStream bout = new MemoryStream();
            while (true)
            {
                int n = inp.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                if (n <= 0)
                    break;
                bout.Write(buf, 0, n);
            }
            inp.Close();

            var cert2 = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(bout.ToArray());

            return new X509Certificate(X509CertificateStructure.GetInstance(cert2.GetRawCertData()));
        }

        try
        {
            certificate.Verify(certificate.GetPublicKey());
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        foreach (X509Certificate candidate in extraCertificates)
        {
            try
            {
                certificate.Verify(candidate.GetPublicKey());
                return candidate;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    static String getCACURL(X509Certificate certificate)
    {
        try
        {
            Asn1Object obj = getExtensionValue(certificate, X509Extensions.AuthorityInfoAccess.Id);
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Asn1Sequence AccessDescriptions = (Asn1Sequence)obj;
            for (int i = 0; i < AccessDescriptions.Count; i++)
            {
                Asn1Sequence AccessDescription = (Asn1Sequence)AccessDescriptions[i];
                if (AccessDescription.Count != 2)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((AccessDescription[0] is DerObjectIdentifier) && ((DerObjectIdentifier)AccessDescription[0]).Id.Equals("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2"))
                    {
                        String AccessLocation = getStringFromGeneralName((Asn1Object)AccessDescription[1]);
                        return AccessLocation == null ? "" : AccessLocation;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return null;
    }

    static Asn1Object getExtensionValue(X509Certificate certificate, String oid)
    {
        byte[] bytes = certificate.GetExtensionValue(new DerObjectIdentifier(oid)).GetDerEncoded();
        if (bytes == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Asn1InputStream aIn = new Asn1InputStream(new MemoryStream(bytes));
        Asn1OctetString octs = (Asn1OctetString)aIn.ReadObject();
        aIn = new Asn1InputStream(new MemoryStream(octs.GetOctets()));
        return aIn.ReadObject();
    }

    private static String getStringFromGeneralName(Asn1Object names)
    {
        Asn1TaggedObject taggedObject = (Asn1TaggedObject) names;
        return Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(Asn1OctetString.GetInstance(taggedObject, false).GetOctets());
    }

    //
    // inner class
    //
    class ValidationData
    {
        public IList<byte[]> crls = new List<byte[]>();
        public IList<byte[]> ocsps = new List<byte[]>();
        public IList<byte[]> certs = new List<byte[]>();
    }

    //
    // member variables
    //
    PdfStamper pdfStamper;
    ISet<X509Certificate> seenCertificates = new HashSet<X509Certificate>();
    IDictionary<PdfName, ValidationData> validated = new Dictionary<PdfName, ValidationData>();

    public static List<X509Certificate> extraCertificates = new List<X509Certificate>();
}
```

You generally use that class like this

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(signedDocument);
FileStream os = new FileStream(ENABLED_PDF, FileMode.Create);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, os, (char)0, true);

AdobeLtvEnabling adobeLtvEnabling = new AdobeLtvEnabling(pdfStamper);
IOcspClient ocsp = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();
ICrlClient crl = new CrlClientOnline();
adobeLtvEnabling.enable(ocsp, crl);

pdfStamper.Close();
```

The original Java class has the limitation that

> the complete certificate chains are assumed to be buildable using AIA entries.

This means that every (non-root) certificate in question contains an URL for downloading its issuer certificate.

This is not always the case. To get around that limitation here, I added a `public static List extraCertificates` into which one can put additional certificates which are tested as issuer certificate candidates if there is no issuer certificate URL in some certificates. Before calling `enable` you have to add those extra certificates as BouncyCastle `X509Certificate` objects.

Comment: I tried with same code but facing issue, posted question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56458787/add-revocation-detail-in-pdf-while-signing-same , can you please check, thanks a lot.

Comment: @sonsha The cause for that issue is that for one certificate in the signature there the associated CRL is offered for download in a base64 encoded form while the code above assumes it to be in a binary, not a base64 encoded text form. You can find an extension of the above code that also handles base64 encoded CRLs [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56461398/1729265).

Comment: The use of `PdfPKCS7` in `enable` restricts the signatures supported to those also supported by iText. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59733096/1729265) `enable` is changed to use BouncyCastle classes instead which support a wider array of signature algorithms, actually wider than is supported by Adobe Reader.