# Add Timestamp for hardware token digital signature and adding LTV not working / throws exception

Tags: c#, pdf, timestamp, itext, digital-signature

This is extended question from this question : [add revocation detail in pdf while signing same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56458787/add-revocation-detail-in-pdf-while-signing-same)

I have signed a pdf using `itextsharp` library and .net core (c#).
after signing pdf I added LTV using `AdobeLtvEnabling` class from previous question. - Till here pdf is working fine.

But when I am trying to embed timestamp in signature, it embeds but in `AdobeLtvEnabling` class's enable method in verification it throws exception :

> Signer SHA256WITH1.2.840.10045.4.3.2 not recognised

Below is the code method for signing:

```
private static byte[] SignPdfWithCert(X509Certificate2 cert, byte[] SourcePdfBytes, Guid userId, string password, int xPlace, int yPlace, int width, int height, int pageNo, string dscPin, Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain, string algorithm, string itemId, Stream imageStream, int MarginXForDSCToSearchText = 5, int MarginYForDSCToSearchText = 5)
{
    var signature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, algorithm);

    PdfReader pdfReader;
    PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        pdfReader = new PdfReader(SourcePdfBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));
    else
        pdfReader = new PdfReader(SourcePdfBytes);
    MemoryStream signedPdf = new MemoryStream();
    PdfStamper pdfStamper;

    pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, signedPdf, '\0', null, true); // Append new digital signature

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) == false)
    {
        pdfStamper.SetEncryption(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password), PdfWriter.AllowCopy, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_256);
    }

    PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;

    signatureAppearance.Location = cert.IssuerName.Name;
    signatureAppearance.Acro6Layers = false;
    signatureAppearance.Layer4Text = PdfSignatureAppearance.questionMark;  //Property neeeds to be set for watermarking behind the signature which indicates signature status as per User's computer. 
    if (imageStream != null)
    {
        signatureAppearance.Layer2Text = "";
        var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageStream);
        signatureAppearance.SignatureGraphic = image;
        signatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC;
    }
    else
    {
        signatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
    }
    signatureAppearance.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED;

    signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(xPlace, yPlace, xPlace + width, yPlace + height), pageNo, string.Concat(itemId, pageNo));

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;

    CspParameters cspp = new CspParameters();
    cspp.KeyContainerName = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName;
    cspp.ProviderName = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName;
    // cspp.ProviderName = "Microsoft Smart Card Key Storage Provider";

    cspp.ProviderType = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType;
    SecureString pwd = GetSecurePin(dscPin);
    cspp.KeyPassword = pwd;
    cspp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt;

    try
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa2 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspp);
    }
    catch
    {
        // ignored- pfx file
    }

    rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
    var url = "http://aatl-timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/aohfewat2389535fnasgnlg5m23";
    var tsc = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(url, null, null, 4096, "SHA-512");
    MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, signature, chain, null, null, tsc, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);

    SourcePdfBytes = signedPdf.ToArray();
    pdfStamper.Close();
    var directory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    var finaltrustedSignedpdf = Path.Combine(directory, "TempFolder", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    if (!Directory.Exists(finaltrustedSignedpdf))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(finaltrustedSignedpdf);
    }
    finaltrustedSignedpdf = Path.Combine(finaltrustedSignedpdf, "LTVSignedpdf.pdf");
    try
    {
        AddLtv(SourcePdfBytes, finaltrustedSignedpdf, new OcspClientBouncyCastle(), new CrlClientOnline());
        var readbytes = File.ReadAllBytes(finaltrustedSignedpdf);
        if (File.Exists(finaltrustedSignedpdf))
        {
            File.Delete(finaltrustedSignedpdf);
        }
        return readbytes;
    }
    catch
    {
        //Unable to add LTV due to no access on CRL URL
        return SourcePdfBytes;
    }
}

public static void AddLtv(byte[] src, string dest, IOcspClient ocsp, ICrlClient crl)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileStream os = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.CreateNew);
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, os, (char)0, true);

    AdobeLtvEnabling adobeLtvEnabling = new AdobeLtvEnabling(pdfStamper);
    adobeLtvEnabling.enable(ocsp, crl);
    pdfStamper.Close();
}
```

it uses `AdobeLtvEnabling` class from previous question
I have used random free timestamp url in above code as my signing certificate does not have timestamp provisioned url in certificate details of cert or CA cert.

This is the exported [cer file](https://www.zeta-uploader.com/en/browse/976820849) without private key of cert

In above code if we remove below lines

```
var url = "http://aatl-timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/aohfewat2389535fnasgnlg5m23";
            var tsc = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(url, null, null, 4096, "SHA-512");
            MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, signature, chain, null, null, tsc, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);
```

with this line

```
MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);
```

then it will generate signed pdf without timestamp. - which is ltv enabled and with green tick mark.

This is other [signed pdf](https://www.zeta-uploader.com/browse/2103052190) without timestamp using different cert token :- For this file **timestamp is provisioned in CA cert** which should be used while adding timestamp in signature. I don't have that token's exported DSC file.

Please guide me on below -
1.Why it is throwing exception and what it suggests? Is it correct way to add timestamp? Can i use free open timestamping services if timestamping url is not present in CA cert. 
2. If Timestamping URL is present in CA cert than how to access that url in object of code. - We don't have such token here , which used in above signed pdf.

Thanks in advance. please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

**Update** : exception : Signer SHA256WITH1.2.840.10045.4.3.2 not recognised.

**Stacktrace:**

```
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SignerUtilities.GetSigner(String algorithm)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7.InitSignature(AsymmetricKeyParameter key)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7..ctor(Byte[] contentsKey, PdfName filterSubtype)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.VerifySignature(String name)
   at Cygnature.App.AdobeLtvEnabling.enable(IOcspClient ocspClient, ICrlClient crlClient) in D:\WorkSpace\Aug2019\Cygnature.Utility\CygnetGSPDSC\AdobeLTVEnabling.cs:line 43
   at Cygnature.App.DigitalSignatureSigningService.AddLtv(Byte[] src, String dest, IOcspClient ocsp, ICrlClient crl) in D:\WorkSpace\Aug2019\Cygnature.Utility\CygnetGSPDSC\DigitalSignatureSigningService.cs:line 557
   at Cygnature.App.DigitalSignatureSigningService.SignPdfWithCert(X509Certificate2 cert, Byte[] SourcePdfBytes, Guid userId, String password, Int32 xPlace, Int32 yPlace, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 pageNo, String dscPin, X509Certificate[] chain, String algorithm, String itemId, Stream imageStream, Int32 MarginXForDSCToSearchText, Int32 MarginYForDSCToSearchText) in D:\WorkSpace\Aug2019\Cygnature.Utility\CygnetGSPDSC\DigitalSignatureSigningService.cs:line 531
```

Comment: Please add the stack trace of the exception. That being said, apparently ecdsa is used which is not supported by itext. Thus, some changes will be needed.

Comment: In a comment to the referenced question you mention that the exception occurs during ` PdfPKCS7 pdfPKCS7 = fields.VerifySignature(name)`. In that case we most likely have to change `AdobeLtvEnabling` to not use itext code to inspect the signature at all, merely to retrieve it.

Comment: I have added stack trace @mkl, what changes do you suggest which i should be  doing? Thanks

Comment: The method `enable` uses the itext `PdfPkcs7` class to retrieve the signer certificate of the signature. That code must be changed to not use that class.

Comment: okay, Any suggestions for alternative, If I don't use that class then how will I add LTV.

Comment: As mentioned above, that class is used only to extract the signer certificate for `AdobeLtvEnabling`. The same can be done more manually using BouncyCastle classes directly. This week and next week I'm mostly offline, thereafter I may look into that if it is not already resolved then.

Comment: ok Thanks. For the 2nd question I asked in this question : _If Timestamping URL is present in CA cert than how to access that url in object of code._  for the signed pdf which I have attached here I debug the cert and I have found OID : 1.2.840.113583.1.1.9.1 - For timestamping but It is the raw data how do I extract  same : refer this ss : https://www.zeta-uploader.com/browse/8522116

Comment: For testing purposes, can you share a signed and time-stamped PDF for which `AdobeLtvEnabling` runs into the exception?

Comment: Hi @mkl,I am able to solve this problem, As I was using wrong pair of timestamp service and wrong token.  
Now it is working. Thanks for your help. But I am still not able to fetch x509extentionvalue of oid : 1.2.840.113583.1.1.9.1. Please help for same. latest correct Signed  pdf : https://www.zeta-uploader.com/browse/897639557 - You can check this file is containing Timestamp url in that extension, how do i fetch same.

Comment: Great, I see you did it. Probably I'll add an answer next week that deals with an implicit part of your original question, LTV enabling an ECDSA signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In her own answer the OP has made clear that after switching to the correct key material for her use case the exception vanished.*

*This answer is about what to do if one gets the exception for the key material one does have to use.*

The exception has message "Signer SHA256WITH1.2.840.10045.4.3.2 not recognised" and stack trace

```
at Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SignerUtilities.GetSigner(String algorithm)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7.InitSignature(AsymmetricKeyParameter key)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7..ctor(Byte[] contentsKey, PdfName filterSubtype)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.VerifySignature(String name)
```

It occurs during the initialization of the iText class `PdfPKCS7` which requests a signer with an invalid algorithm name, "SHA256WITH1.2.840.10045.4.3.2". The OID 1.2.840.10045.4.3.2 stands for ecdsa-with-SHA256, and that illuminates the cause of the error here: The signature in question is an elliptic curve signature but iText 5.x does not support ECDSA algorithms.

To LTV-enable such a signature using the `AdobeLtvEnabling` class (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52447274/1729265)) nonetheless, we, therefore, have to remove the use of `PdfPKCS7` in it.

We replace it by more generic BouncyCastle classes as follows, in the method `enable` replace the loop

```
List<String> names = fields.GetSignatureNames();
foreach (String name in names)
{
    PdfPKCS7 pdfPKCS7 = fields.VerifySignature(name);
    PdfDictionary signatureDictionary = fields.GetSignatureDictionary(name);
    X509Certificate certificate = pdfPKCS7.SigningCertificate;
    addLtvForChain(certificate, ocspClient, crlClient, getSignatureHashKey(signatureDictionary, encrypted));
}
```

by

```
List<String> names = fields.GetSignatureNames();
foreach (String name in names)
{
    PdfDictionary signatureDictionary = fields.GetSignatureDictionary(name);
    PdfString contents = signatureDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS);
    CmsSignedData signedData = new CmsSignedData(contents.GetOriginalBytes());
    IX509Store certs = signedData.GetCertificates("COLLECTION");
    foreach (SignerInformation signerInformation in signedData.GetSignerInfos().GetSigners())
    {
        ArrayList certList = new ArrayList(certs.GetMatches(signerInformation.SignerID));
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)certList[0];
        addLtvForChain(certificate, ocspClient, crlClient, getSignatureHashKey(signatureDictionary, encrypted));
    }
}
```

Now a wider array of signature algorithms is supported, actually wider than is supported by Adobe Reader.

Comment: Appreciate your knowledge on this, helped a lot.   can you please review this question too if that's possible :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61728461/adjust-width-for-image-in-itextsharp-while-adding-digital-signature-in-graphic-a

Answer (score 1):

I was trying with wrong pair of DSC (USB token) and timestamp URL. That was the reson it was throwing exception to me while adding LTV.

Then I tried with actual global sign dsc and url embedded in it's property of x509 extension then it worked and I was able to sign PDF : zeta-uploader.com/browse/897639557

> Reference Code for fetching timestamp URL:

```
  X509Certificate2 cert = null;


  X509Store x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
  x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

   //manually chose the certificate in the store
  Selectcert: X509Certificate2Collection select = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(x509Store.Certificates, null, null, X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);

   if (select.Count > 0)
   cert = select[0]; //This will get us the selected certificate in "cert" object

foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Extension extension in cert.Extensions)
                {
                    if (extension.Oid.Value == "1.2.840.113583.1.1.9.1")
                    {
                        var ext = extension;
                        AsnEncodedData asndata = new AsnEncodedData(extension.Oid, extension.RawData);
                        var rawdata = asndata.RawData;
                        var val = Encoding.Default.GetString(rawdata);
                        var timestampUrl = TrimNonAscii(val);
                        timestampUrl = timestampUrl.Substring(timestampUrl.IndexOf("http"));
                    }
                }
```

> Code for appending timestamp in make signature

```
  var tsc = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(timestampUrl , null, null, 4096, "SHA-512");  
  //here timestamp url is fetched from above code
  MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, signature, chain, null, null, tsc, 
  0, CryptoStandard.CADES);
```